# Reputation gained tooltip for top tag is squished

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, tooltips

On the new [user activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/222623/grgarside?tab=topactivity), there is a top tag section of the reputation box, which shows the reputation earned next to the name of the tag.

However the hover tooltip is unnecessarily squished horizontally making it hard to read. This seems to be regardless of the length of the tag.

> [image]
>   [image]

Could the width of this tooltip be extended, like the other tooltip for the total reputation earned?

> [image]

Comment: Specifically a duplicate because of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253483/131713) to a "master bug list" type question for the new profile page feature.